# Lightbox / Mixitup Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox2, mixitup

I've built a gallery that utilizes lightbox as well as mixitup to filter images.

After activating the lightbox on an image, i'd like the scrolling to be limited to whatever the active filter selection is. I know this is possible to group images wihtin the gallery using the data-lightbox attribute, however my gallery also has an option to view all images in which case it would need to navigate through all the images, not just one specific set.

Is it possible to link the data-lightbox attribute to mixitup's data-filter attribute somehow?

Thank you in advance for any help that can be offered.

Comment: do you have some code for us?

Comment: I can't paste my entire pages files, however i can include a jsfiddle withan example of the html section for the gallery. it then uses mixitup and lightbox's standard javascript and css. This is the basic idea of how it's framed. Let me know what other information you would need. Thanks again, I realize it would be ideal to have all the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/evanweston/yqfw33uc/1/